# How to insert data in child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i met a problem when tried to put some data in my block. I have div structure like this:

```
<div class="1">
    <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
            <div class="4"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="1">
    <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
            <div class="4"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="5"></div>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

and i need to place some data only in`<div class="4"></div>`

when i use this JS:

```
function sendDataChild(btn) {
var form = $(btn).closest('FORM[name=answer-form]');
var data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        form[0].reset();
        $("div.4").html(data.error_name);
    },
    error: function (xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
});
return false;
};
```

it puts data in all div's with class = "4"

I tried to find parent, but it just put data in parent:

```
$("div.4").parent().html(data.error_name);
```

Can U advise how to make it right?
P.S 
I used numbers just for example.)

Comment: you must not start element id or class name with a number.

Comment: How do you distinguish between all `.4`, i mean in which `div.4`, you want to insert the data ?

Comment: it is no good to start class and or ids with numbers have a look also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: You said you want to put some data only on `<div class="4"></div>` and there is more that one div with class property set to 4. Which one do you want to put your data?

Comment: when and how is `sendDataChild` function called ?

Comment: that is it. i can put data in first .4 or in fifth .4 there are lot of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your button is under one `div.1` you can replace your

```
$("div.4").html(data.error_name);
```

with

```
$(btn).closest("div.1").find("div.4").html(data.error_name);
```

Edit: Like the comments say you should not start your class names with numbers, but I hope this are just placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you identify your div by id and use the append method.